# How to use an optional argument?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing this script to work as a fast draft. It opens my text editor with date and time, so I can insert some draft text to save quickly.

**1.** At first I'd like to append the date and time at the beginning of the file instead of at the end, as `>> $file` does.  But I guess that it is not so easy, so this is not my priority.

**2.** I defined an argument `$1`. If I have only few words to insert I believe that it is better to run `draft "foo foo"` instead of opening the editor to write just few words.

Well, it is working but with the argument the last line is not necessary. So I'd like to make it a conditional line. If I pass no argument, then open editor; else none.

Any help to improve my script?

```
#!/bin/bash
file=rascunho
folder=/home/$USER/
#linha=$(wc -l < $file)
content=$1
#rm $folder$file
printf "\n\n" >> $file
#echo " " >> $file
echo "------< $(date "+%b %d, %Y - %H:%M:%S") >------" >> $file
echo "$1" >> $file
exec leafpad  $file
```

Comment: Use a version control system, it will keep track of such stuff for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `if` to check. For example, you can do something like this instead of the last two lines in your script above:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  echo "$1" >> $file
else
  exec leafpad $file
fi
```

This says: if the first argument is not an empty string (this is what `-n` test does), then run `echo`, else run `leafpad`.

You can read more about this here:

- http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 2):

To be more generic, use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` -- this lets you write

```
draft use many words without quoting.
```

```
#!/bin/bash
file=rascunho
printf "\n\n------< %s >------\n" "$(date "+%b %d, %Y - %T")" >> $file
# if any arguments were given, write them to the file, else edit the file
if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "$@" >> $file
else
    exec leafpad $file
fi
```

To write a line at the beginning of the file, you can use a grouping construct:

```
{ echo "first line"; cat $file; } > temp && mv temp $file
```